# how to get an array as output using scipy.leastsq?

Tags: python, matlab, least-squares

i really need help on a code. i'm trying to translate a matlab code into python.
i used lsqonlin (matlab) and got an array as an output, i tried the same with scipy.leastsq but the output was a single value, what should i use in order to get an array ? 
here's the code in matlab:

```
fun= @(phi) sin(2*phi)/(2*phi)-gamma;
 InitialGuess = pi/12;
 %[phi_1(ir),~,~]=fsolve(fun,InitialGuess,optimset('Display','off'));
 lb=0;ub=2.25;
 [phi_1(ii,jj),~,~]=lsqnonlin(fun,InitialGuess,lb,ub,optimset('Display','off'));
```

after correction, the output is a single value array, whereas, i need various values in order to plot. code below:

```
from math import pi 
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
def  f(phi):
    y= np.sin(2*phi)/(2*phi) - gamma
    return y

x0 = pi/12
phi1 = least_squares(f,x0)
print(phi1)
```

and here's the output:

```
active_mask: array([0.+0.j])
        cost: (-3.249913819664981e-06+5.139025241135326e-07j)
         fun: array([0.00020095+0.00255738j])
        grad: array([-0.00013185-0.00167795j])
         jac: array([[-0.65612047]])
     message: '`xtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 15
        njev: 5
  optimality: 0.0016831233538848116
      status: 3
     success: True
           x: array([1.54956525+0.06919657j])
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Can we take a look at the code you wrote that was only returning a scalar?

Comment: sorry for delay, i've corrected it, now the output is an array with only one element,          yet, it's not the wanted result (i need various values of phi in order to plot )                              from math import pi 
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
def  f(phi):
    y= np.sin(2*phi)/(2*phi) - gamma
    return y

x0 = pi/12
phi1 = least_squares(f,x0)
print(phi1)